# How to convert a S5 presentation into PDF?

Tags: pdf, slideshow, presentation, restructuredtext

I am using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) & [rst2s5](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/slide-shows.html) to create [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) slide presentations. It is great but I also want to have the presentation in PDF. How can I convert S5 to PDF?

S5 are HTML based... one of S5 features is to create print-outs of your presentation. So when I try to use a PDF printer from the browser I just get print-outs. I want to a PDF with the slides, 1 slide per page and all the formatting, colors and font-size from the original presentation.

Comment: there is no tag for "S5"... and I don't have enough reputation to create tags :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://schettino72.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/slide-presentations-in-restructuredtext-s5-pdf/

Comment: page behind the link is about using the nonfree software `prince` to convert from s5-output to pdf. however there also seems to be a custom stylesheet (page.css) involved. is such included in prince?
to me, rst2pdf seems like a better variant since freely available and usable for commercial application without the USD 495 tag of prince...

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to create pdf or don't mind getting a different theme for the pdf, you could also use one these:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rst2beamer/0.6.6

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rst2odp/0.2.3

http://web.archive.org/web/20130718071252/http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS52.html

It is also possible to theme these to get the same theme as for the S5 presentation, but it takes a bit more work. I'm currently using rst2pdf with my own custom theme.

The latter link, for example, suggests using the following commandline:

```
rst2pdf slides.txt -b1 -s slides.style
```

with slides.style containing:

```
{"pageSetup": {
    "width": "16cm",
    "height": "9cm",
    "margin-top": "0cm",
    "margin-bottom": "0cm",
    "margin-left": "0cm",
    "margin-right": "0cm",
    "margin-gutter": "0cm",
    "spacing-header": "5mm",
    "spacing-footer": "5mm",
    "firstTemplate": "cutePage"
},
"pageTemplates" : {
    "cutePage": {
        "frames": [
            ["10%", "10%", "80%", "80%"]
        ],
        "background" : "background.svg"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: any suggestions/references for creating a css-theme for rst2pdf would be welcome for further reading ;) thanks

Comment: i added examples from the web archive... but it still looks like hell here.. it doesn't look very straightforward, in short...